# Minimize sum of distances between mutually disjoint bipartite pair of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I have a multidimensionnal array which represent distances between two group of points (colored by blue and red respectively).

```
import numpy as np
distance=np.array([[30,18,51,55],
                   [35,15,50,49],
                   [36,17,40,32],
                   [40,29,29,17]])
```

Each column represent the red dot and rows are for blue dots. Values in this matrix represent the distance between red and blue dots. Here is a sketch to understand what it looks like:

[image]

Question: **How to find the minimum of the sum of distances between mutually disjoint (blue, red) pairs?**

## Attempt

I am expecting to find 1=1, 2=2, 3=3 and 4=4 in the above image. However, if i use a simple argmin numpy function like:

```
for liste in distance:
    np.argmin(liste)
```

the result is

```
1
1
1
3
```

because the 2 red point is the nearest of 1,2 and 3 blue point.

Is there a way to do something generic in that case to make things better? I mean without using a lot of if statements and a while function.

Comment: Why is 1,1,1,3 not the expected output? And why it is not 2,1,4,3 if you process the distance for blue points 1,2,3,4 sequentially and remove the points found?

Comment: @BillHuang I believe OP is asking for the correspondence that minimize the total pair-wise distance.

Comment: Because two points can't be at the same places. Here the 2 red point can't be assigned to 1, 2 and 3 blue point.
I can't do it sequentially because the order of point could change and I want that each red point is assigned to it's nearest blue point.

Comment: @Panda50 how do you want to deal with the case where two red points have the same blue point as their closest?

Comment: @Eshan let assume that red point number two is equally spaced from blue point 1 and 2. Red point 1 is nearest blue point 1 so blue point 1 can't be red point two! As Quang Hoang say, I'd like to know if there is a simple way to compute the minimal pair-wise distance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is known as the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in operations management and can be solved efficiently by [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). In your case, the distance can be viewed as a kind of "cost" function which is going to be minimized in its total.

Luckily, `scipy` has a nice `linear_sum_assignment()` (see [official docs and example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)) implemented, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. The function returns the matched indices.

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
distance=np.array([[30,18,51,55],
                   [35,15,50,49],
                   [36,17,40,32],
                   [40,29,29,17]])

row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(distance)

# result
col_ind
Out[79]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
row_ind
Out[80]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution Bill and thank for the documentation and the wiki pages!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.permutations` to find all possible solutions. Then, you calculate which solution minimize the total pair-wise distance.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

distance=np.array([[30,18,51,55],[35,15,50,49],[36,17,40,32],[40,29,29,17]])

permutation=[x for x in itertools.permutations([0,1,2,3],4)]
x_opt=permutation[0]
d_opt=sum([distance[i,x_opt[i]] for i in range(len(distance[0]))])
for x in permutation:
    d=sum([distance[i,x[i]] for i in range(len(distance[0]))])
    if d<d_opt:
        (d_opt,x_opt)=(d,x)
print(x_opt)
```

The result will be in this case:

```
(0,1,2,3)
```

Comment: This is really massive overkill

Comment: Thanks Lauriane, it could work but it's a bit hard to write.

Comment: Caution: How many possible solutions are there for n red points? There are `n!`, And `15! > 1.3 trillion`.